# I can only start 1 of my 5 animations

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have several animations for this model that I was able to access previously in the action editor, but now I can only access my walking animation. Can anyone tell me why and how I can access my other animations again?

[image]

Comment: What about the action editor [dropdown menu](https://i.imgur.com/Lawo3J4.png)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select your armature:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to make your armature visible, and select it
- In the *Dopesheet* window, stay in *Action Editor* mode
- In the dropdown menu, select the animation you want

[image]

Comment: You are correct sir. I thought I had my armature already selected in pose mode, but I guess I had not. This worked for me!